# shift a variable one position down

Tags: r

In R, I have a variable called test which has 19 elements

```
    > test
 [1]  2014538.23  4487086.00  1334284.39 -1043651.88 -2717872.52  7823769.24 -3362387.51  2769196.46
 [9] -3252671.72 -3799388.26   -91410.81  1631932.15  6462360.52 -4523175.28  4876797.43 -1900613.35
[17]   188371.84   484573.51 -2483920.48
```

and I would like to move all elements down by one position, and the first element would then be NA, increasing the total elements to 20.

If I try:

```
lag(test,n=1)
```

I get the following elements:

```
> lag(test,n=1)
 [1]          NA  2014538.23  4487086.00  1334284.39 -1043651.88 -2717872.52  7823769.24 -3362387.51
 [9]  2769196.46 -3252671.72 -3799388.26   -91410.81  1631932.15  6462360.52 -4523175.28  4876797.43
[17] -1900613.35   188371.84   484573.51
```

which are still 19. How can I implement this?

Comment: Do you mean `c(NA, test)`?

Comment: `c(rep(NA,n), test)` where n is the number of NAs you want to put would do the trick

Comment: Yes @Sotos it was probably a silly question I got stuck somehow!

Comment: No worries. Happens to all :). I couldn't find a relevant dupe so I added an answer

Comment: Thanks - seems to happen a lot to me sometimes!! :) I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to add NA not shift your data with a `lag`. In this case you can just concatenate NA in your vector, i.e.

```
c(NA, test)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code-

```
> append(values=NA,x=test,after=0)
```

**Note**: You can use `after` parameter in the above function to provide position at which value is to be appended.

**Input Data:**

```
 > test <- c(2014538.23 , 4487086.00 , 1334284.39 ,-1043651.88 ,-2717872.52 , 7823769.24 ,-3362387.51 , 2769196.46,
              -3252671.72 ,-3799388.26 ,  -91410.81 , 1631932.15  ,6462360.52, -4523175.28 , 4876797.43 ,-1900613.35,
              188371.84 ,  484573.51 ,-2483920.48)
```